# Would calling the alert() function in a Node.js script freeze the entire server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Since Node.js has a single thread, would calling a function like `alert()`, which waits for a user, freeze the entire server? Or does Node.js know to prevent functions such as that?

Comment: I don't think there is `alert` in Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will freeze the server. You should remember that alert() function is a property of browser window objects. alert() is not really part of JavaScript; it's just a facility available to JavaScript code in that environment. Also alert() function is not available in node.js

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would freeze the server, for the reason you described. That's the reason `alert` doesn't exist in NodeJS.

[`alert` is a property of the `window` object](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html#simple-dialogs) anyway, which only browsers provide.